# Error when push to AWS SQS from EKS cluster pod with @aws-sdk/client-sqs npm package

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-eks

I'm using `@aws/client-sqs` npm package in AWS EKS cluster to push messages onto a standard SQS queue and getting the below error:

```
CredentialsProviderError: 169.254.170.23 is not a valid container metadata service hostname
    at getCmdsUri (/test/node_modules/@smithy/credential-provider-imds/dist-cjs/fromContainerMetadata.js:57:19)
    at /test/node_modules/@smithy/credential-provider-imds/dist-cjs/fromContainerMetadata.js:16:38
    at retry (/test/node_modules/@smithy/credential-provider-imds/dist-cjs/remoteProvider/retry.js:5:19)
    at /test/node_modules/@smithy/credential-provider-imds/dist-cjs/fromContainerMetadata.js:15:36
    at /test/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/chain.js:12:39
    at async coalesceProvider (/test/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/memoize.js:14:24)
    at async /test/node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/memoize.js:33:24
    at async /test/node_modules/@smithy/core/dist-cjs/middleware-http-auth-scheme/httpAuthSchemeMiddleware.js:35:23
    at async /test/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-sqs/dist-cjs/send-message.js:7:18
    at async /test/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26 {
  tryNextLink: false
}
```

And the code is:

```js
const { SQSClient, SendMessageCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-sqs');

const sqsClient = new SQSClient();

const sendCommand = new SendMessageCommand({ QueueUrl: '<queue-url>', MessageBody: '{"a":1}' });
sqsClient
  .send(sendCommand)
  .then(() => console.log('Message sent!'))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Looks like `169.254.170.23` is more of a local network IP. Is the SQS queue URL somehow resolving to that local IP?

We have dev and prod EKS clusters. It is working in dev env but not in prod . The difference I see is that we are running `coredns` and `kube-proxy` side car containers in prod EKS cluster inside each node group but not in dev.

Can anyone help me understand what's the issue here?

Comment: I am also running into this, using @aws-sdk/client-s3@3.489.0

Comment: Can you try `unset AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI` in your environment and try to push to SQS?

Answer (score 1):

`169.254.170.23` is the AWS metadata IP address for containers (EKS pod identity) and best guess from the error it looks like version of the SDK used doesn't support it yet.

`printenv | grep "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI"` will return `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI=http://169.254.170.23/v1/credentials` in this case.